# Submersion and immersion

Tags: differential-topology

I googled wiki about submersion and immersion. Wiki states that submersion is dual to immersion. I wonder where this duality relationship comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a pretty sloppy notion of duality: If you put a $k$-manifold in $R^n$ with maximal derivative rank, there are three choices:

$$
k < n \\
k = n \\
k > n
$$
The middle choice is generally uninteresting (at least for compact manifolds without boundary). The other two correspond to "immersion" and "submersion".

By "sloppy", I mean that there's no "dualizing" map described -- there's no way to take a submersion and generate a corresponding immersion, which if it is dualized brings you back to the original submersion; not only does the article not mention such a map, I don't know of one, either (I'd like to!).  Contrast that with, say, Poincare duality, where the dualizing map is quite clear.

Comment: Well, perhaps duality akin to the sense that a linear map $T\colon V \to W$ is injective if and only if the dual map $T^*\colon W^*\to V^*$ is surjective ...

Comment: OK...but what would the dual map be in this case? I still don't see it. (And apparently, the OP isn't convinced by my answer, so he and I both await enlightenment.)

Comment: The transpose of $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ (which is the linear inclusion of $\Bbb R^2\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^3$) is the projection.

Comment: Sorry...by "in this case" I meant "in the case of submersion/immersion." I knew about the dual for linear maps. :)